# What prevents an electron with initial energy qV to be subsequently accelerated with the same potential?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

There's a uniform force acting on a charge (F=qE=qV/d) inside a plate capacitor. So if I have two sets of parallel plate accelerators, both with potential V, why an accelerated electron coming out of the first accelerator (with energy qV) cannot be subsequently accelerated in the next accelerator?

Clearly it's impossible from energy conservation arguments, but what exactly prevents this? What's the difference between an electron at rest and an electron in motion in this context?

(In the mechanical analogy of marble rolling down and up a hill, what is the electrical equivalent of climbing up the hill against gravity in this setup?)

Comment: Why is it clearly impossible from energy conservation arguments?  You'll have to explain.  It seems perfectly possible to me.

Comment: @garyp - this is essentially a follow up to a previous question on synchrotrons and why rf, not electrostatic, fields are used. You can't use the same electrostatic field to keep accelerating an orbiting charge faster and faster, just like the marble analogy I tried, or just like one battery can't bootstrap electrons to higher and higher energies.

Comment: You can't us a synchrotron because a static field cannot continuously increase if it's in a circle.  But you can add electric fields linearly, e.g. using capacitors, as many as you like.

Answer (score 0):

When you use only one static voltage source with voltage V continuously connected to the capacitors (in series or parallel), the maximum potential energy difference and thus gain in kinetic energy an electron can experience is $qV$.  This follows from the electric field $\vec E=- ∇ V $ or $∇×\vec E=0$ which means that the energy gained by the electron between two locations in an electrostatic field is independent of the path taken.

However, if you charge your capacitors to a voltage $V$ at your voltage source and then connect them in series, then you have a potential difference $2·V$ which the electron can run through subsequently and gain a potential energy $2·qV$. This can, in principle, be extended to a large number $N$ of capacitors to achieve a potential difference $N·V$ to achieve a large kinetic electron energy. This is is similar to the voltage multiplication cascade circuit using rectifiers in the Cockcroft–Walton generator (actually invented years before by Greinacher) which was used for particle acceleration and won them the Nobel Prize in 1951.